# zoom image when mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am trying to make more zoom when mouse hover on zoomed image. i mean when cusror hover on zoomed image, some part like square, rectangle, circle e.t.c part of image should zoom.
i have the following code. please suggest me how can i achieve more zoom after zooming the image by onclick.

```
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="overlayContent">
 <img id="imgBig" src="" alt="" width="400" />
 </div><div class="imgSmall"><img src="xyz" 
 id="ProductPhotoImg">
         </div>
       </div>
 <script>
 $("#ProductPhotoImg").click(function(){
 $("#imgBig").attr("src",$(this).attr('src'));
 $("#overlay").show();
 $("#overlayContent").show();
  });

 $("#imgBig").click(function(){

$("#imgBig").attr("src", "");
$("#overlay").hide();
$("#overlayContent").hide();
});
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC

  $("#overlay").hide(); 
  $( "#overlayContent" ).hide();
}
});
</script>
<style>
#overlay{
 position: fixed; 
 padding-right:10px;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
 top: 0px; 
 left: 0px; 
 background-color: #000; 
 opacity: 0.7;
 filter: alpha(opacity = 70) !important;
 display: none;
 z-index: 100;

}
#overlayContent{
position: fixed;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.7); 
-moz-transform: scale(1.6);
-o-transform: scale(1.6);
transform: scale(1.6);
align-content:center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: none;
z-index: 100;
top: 100px;
padding-right: 24em;
padding-left: 14.3em;
top:16.2em;
}
#contentGallery{
margin: 0px auto;
}
#imgBig, .imgSmall, #ProductPhotoImg{
 cursor: -webkit-zoom-in; cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
 }
</style>
```

This code is for onclick zoom.but i want further zoom on mouse hover for zoomed image(like when mouseover on image only hoverd part of image should be zoomed), please sort out my issue friends.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you want to zoom on a part of a zoomed image then you need a magnifying glass like this. http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3

Comment: is that open source?

Comment: I have no idea, just search for jquery magnify glass.  there's a few out there. here's another one -- http://mlens.musings.it/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is with the :hover pseudo class. all you do is..

```
// Name class
.class {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.class:hover {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

You can change those numbers to whatever you'd like but you should also look at other cool pseudo classes you can use in css! :) Hope this helps!

Comment: css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/image.php i want something like this . my code is with onclick zoom. but i need further zoom after zoomed image like the link i given

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try css hover?

like:

```
.myClass{
    height: 100px;
    transition: 1s;
}
.myClass:hover{
    height: 200px;
}
```

at the click event you call a javascript function like:

```
function myFunc(object){
    object.className += "myClass";
}
```

Comment: but i have some other functionality on hover... so my need is to on click image for zoom, then hover on image, only hovered part of image should be zoomed further

Comment: ah, you need to click... try to add a class (with javascript, jQuery, whatever) to the object, where this class have the hover css effect, it will make a "clean code"

Comment: Send it as a parameter `myFunc(this)` and, at the function, you add the class like `object.className += " myClass"`. this should work

Comment: code which i posted is perfectly working. But i need further zoom like magnifying zoom, where if mousehver pointer on zoomed image, some part of image should be zoomed

Comment: can u please write that code and where to add what u suggested

Comment: now, if you need to zoom the image without increasing the size of the div, is a little harder to think... try googling a little bit more, and try to be more specific at your request, if possible

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/image.php i want something like this . my code is with onclick zoom. but i need further zoom after zoomed image like the link i given

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easier :

```
.normalpic {
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
}
.normalpic:hover {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

This will make the image 2x larger on hover

Comment: this can be used for zoom further for zoomed image like magnify zoom?

Comment: You want to zoom zoomed img?

Comment: code which i posted is perfectly working. But i need further zoom like magnifying zoom, where if mousehver pointer on zoomed image, some part of image should be zoomed

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/image.php i want further zoom for zoomed image

Comment: Ah... I got it now.. lemme check